# Weird AF_INET & SOCK_STREAM socket behavior on linux

Tags: linux, sockets

I have two simple processes running on two different linux machines, a client and a server, they communicate with each other using `AF_INET|SOCK_STREAM` socket, the client sends a short command string to server, then the server responds with a VERY long character string(about 78KB), when client receives all these 78KB, it exits, that's all, here comes the weird thing:

The client `recv` all 78KB from socket without error, but only 3415Bytes are valid, the remaining bytes are all NULL-terminating `\0`, that means `strlen(recv_buffer) != 78KB`.

I run the client many times, results are same.

I tried to modify `SO_RCVBUF` to `160KB`(default is `80KB`) for client, but nothing changes.

I used Wireshark to confirm the TCP packets, all `78KB` bytes are ACKed.

More info about client:

```
kernel.osrelease = 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64
kernel.version = #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 19:48:22 GMT 2011
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 92736        123648  185472
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096        16384   3956736
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096        87380   3956736
net.core.wmem_max = 131071
net.core.rmem_max = 131071
net.core.wmem_default = 124928
net.core.rmem_default = 124928
```

Any clue? Very appreciate.

Comment: Are you sure that `recv` is returning all 78KB? It returns the number of bytes that it read, you need to call it in a loop until you get everything.

Comment: If you want more help, show the code of the client's receive loop.

Comment: When you used Wireshark, were the bytes intact?  Can you try running on a single machine also?  And can you show us the receiving code?

Comment: @Barmar After I modify the code, I encounter another problem, when I call `recv` with the 3rd argument `len` known at compilation time(e.g. `len == 1024` or `len == sizeof(local_buffer)`), everything works fine, but if the 3rd argument `len` is known at run-time(e.g. it is assigned from a caller function), it seems `recv` fills the `local_buffer` with many NULL-terminating bytes, that means `strlen(local_buffer) != 78KB`.

Comment: @Barmar BTW, I'm using a embedded arm-gcc provided by Marvell, not the standard GNU GCC.

Comment: I don't think the compiler matters, this is a kernel function. `recv()` doesn't null-terminate the buffer (it can be used with binary data), you should not be using `strlen()` on it. That's why it returns the number of bytes it filled into the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

> The client recv all 78KB from socket

No. You are vanishingly unlikely to receive 78kb in a single recv() call. Clearly you aren't receiving 78kb at all, you are only receiving 3415 bytes.

> without error

Apparently that's all you checked. You didn't check the value returned by `recv()` for confirmation. Calling `strlen()` on the receive buffer instead is simply not valid.

Fiddling around with the socket receive buffer won't fix this. You are vanishingly unlikely to receive 78kb in a single `recv()` call. What you receive is dictated by TCP, mostly by the path MTU, and isn't under your control at all. You have to loop.

Comment: Sorry, I made a VERY stupid mistake in my code, all my fault, waste your time.

Comment: After I modify the code, I encounter another problem, when I call `recv` with the 3rd argument `len` known at compilation time(e.g. `len == 1024` or `len == sizeof(local_buffer)`), everything works fine, but if the 3rd argument `len` is known at run-time(e.g. it is assigned from a caller function), it seems `recv` fills the `local_buffer` with many NULL-terminating bytes, that means `strlen(local_buffer) != 78KB`.

Comment: BTW, I'm using a embedded arm-gcc provided by Marvell, not the standard GNU GCC.